# Databinding Issue With Custom ObservableCollection Properties

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, observablecollection

I'm making a small personal finance program that uses "envelopes" as the budgeting method. I'm mostly doing this as a means to learn WPF & MVVM. I've run into a problem where I can't databind to the custom properties I created in my custom ObservableCollection, seen here:

```
public class ObservableEnvelopeCollection : ObservableCollection<Envelope>
{
    public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            decimal total = 0;
            foreach (Envelope env in this)
            {
                total += env.Balance;
            }
            return total;
        }
    }

    public decimal SavingsTotal
    {
        get
        {
            blah blah. . .
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to databind my datagrid to the collection with no trouble, however below my datagrid I have labels that I need to display the total of balances for the envelopes in the collection. I'm able to databind to the Count property of the collection, which is a property of the parent ObservableCollection class, but I can't databind to Total or SavingsTotal from my custom class.
The label is just blank when the program is run, and if I use the VS2010 designer and go to the little databinding wizard for the label's Content, it has 'Total' underlined and shows the tooltip: "Path item 'Total' could not be resolved." Again, if I change Path to EnvColl.Count it works.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=EnvColl.Total}"/>
```

One more note, in my ViewModel I can access the Total and SavingsTotal properties in my collection with no problem, it's just in XAML/databinding that it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried with BindsDirectlyToSource=true on the Binding?

Answer (score 0):

Bah! I hate when things like this happen... I went to add BindsDirectlyToSource=true per Kent and added it to the wrong place, causing a build error. I then removed it and rebuilt, and the databinding suddenly started working. . . :\ I had rebuilt the solution several times with no luck, but causing a compile error then removing it made things start working. Wonder if there's something buggy in 2010's compiler...?

Answer (score 0):

vs2010

(as always some new commers might need to know about this issue.)

it happened to me when I ran the app on debug mode many times and suddently I have to kill it/stop debugger, then I notice that it does not know when it has to recompile code.

I notice that if I close and reopen the app/solution that helps a lot. if you are running in debugging mode definitely you have to do this every so often.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted a couple of years ago, but I had a similar problem where I had a `Grid` which contained a `Label` and a `DataGrid`.  I was able to set the `ItemsSource` of my `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection`, but I couldn't access the desired properties in my `Label`.  So what I did was set the `DataContext` of my containing `Grid` to the `ObservableCollection`, then I used the `RelativeSource` property of my binding to find the Ancestor (`Grid`).  The syntax looked something like this:

```
<Grid DataContext = "{Binding MyObservableCollection}">
    <Label Content = "{Binding MyDesiredProperty}"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestoryType={x:Type Grid}}}">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I think that achieves what the original poster was looking for.  And hopefully if not it can help some others.